# Overlay doesn't cover overflow:scroll; Modal isn't fixed

Tags: css

Demo: http://jsbin.com/zijisaxoke/1/edit?html,css,output

I have a scrollable container with a content div inside of it (assume variable width of the content div). However, the container has a fixed width of 100% (could also change).

I also have a modal, which has an absolute-positioned grey overlay. My goal is make the grey overlay cover the entire scrollable content of the container, but right now it only covers the initial viewport size. I'd also like to make the modal itself fixed to the left-top side of the container, regardless of scroll position, but it seems `position: fixed` doesn't respect the parent's `position: relative`.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.content {
  width: 2000px;
  height: 300px;
}
.overlay {
  z-index: 200;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.7;
  top: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   background-color: #000;
}
.modal {
  z-index: 500;
  position: fixed;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="stuff">hi</div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">aaa</div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="modal">Hello</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I keep the modal fixed relatively inside of the container, and keep the overlay covering the entire scrollable area of the div?

Comment: Position fixed always calculates it's position from the window and ignores relative positions. If you want this behaviour you need to use position absolute and manipulate the overlay position with JavaScript on scroll event.

Comment: @SimonJentsch that's good to know. How would I manipulate the overlay position, though, if everything is relative to the scrollable viewport?

Comment: You need to add a scroll event on the scrollable `.container` class in JavaScript. Then you set top of the overlay to the `scrollTop` property of the container everytime this events fires. I'll add the answer later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a JS solution:

```
$('.container').on('scroll', function() {
  var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
  $('.overlay').css('top', scrollTop);
  $('.overlay').css('bottom', -scrollTop);
});
```

and the corresponding JS Bin:
http://jsbin.com/xahehodeqe/3/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ganedahelo/4/edit?html,css,js,console,output I made it work horizontally. Thanks!